# Do you need to pack commonjs bundle in a React Component library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, rollup

I have been following tutorials online and I seem to see an approach where `em` and `commonjs` are packed into a library using bundlers like rollup. From my knowledge, I think commonjs bundle is important when building libraries that will run in Node.js or both Node.js and browsers.
However for reactjs, the library is intended to run in browsers and I don't get it why we need a commonjs bundle. Especially with how browsers are getting modern rapidly.

I may not be knowing the importance of commonjs bundle for libraries intended to run in browsers and I am contemplating about omitting it in the final packaged library [I am building](https://npmjs.com/package/react-loading-indicators) because I see nothing break when I test omit it. I appreciate if you educate me here, im quite unaware.